# overloading operators and behavior of static member variable

Tags: c++

I am running the following code and expecting that output window should display number of points equals to three at the end of program. There is some problem with point p3, where I created new point and initialize with p2 after using increment operator. I don't understand what is wrong. Definitely missing something here. Need help please!

Thanks for reading.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {

    private:
        int x, y;
        static int  count;

    public:
    Point(): x(0), y(0) { count++; }
    Point(int x1, int y1) {
        x = x1; y = y1;
        count++;
    }

    int getCount() const { return count; }

    Point operator=(Point &p) {
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;

        return *this;
    }

    Point operator++() {
        x++; y++;
        return *this;
    }

    void print() { cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl; }
};

int Point::count = 0;

//================ Driver Program ============

int main() {

    Point p1;
    Point p2(1, 1);

    p1.print();
    p2.print();

    Point p3 = ++p2;
    p3.print();

    cout << "Number of points: "<<p1.getCount() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`p3` is a copy of `p2`, but you don't have a copy constructor that increments the counter.

You would need a `Point(const Point&)` with a `++counter` (in addition to copy the `x` and `y` members).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you expect, that the program prints, that the number of points is 3, you are actually missing a couple of things:

- First of all, you haven't declared a copy or move constructor, so the compiler will generate a default one for you. That one will be called when you create your `p3`, and that default one won't increase your counter. A copy constructor is something like `Point(const Point&) { ++counter; }`.
- Your overloaded operators actually create copies by themselves. Therefore, if you add a copy constructor, the pointer count will propably be at 4 or 5 and not at 3. To change this, you should change the return type of both operators from `Point` to `Point&`. That way, these operators will return a reference of the same object instead of a copy of it - which means, that no copy is created and therefor the copy-constructor is not called at the end of each operator, but only if you actually create a copy (like `p3`).

Comment: Thanks. Its working.  When I added a copy constructor, I got count=3. But when I added another assignment statement p3 = ++p2, I get count=5 why not 4 and without returning reference?

Comment: @bell without returning reference, the compiler will call your copy constructor once you do ++p2, as you return a copy (and not a reference) of p2, and then it creates another copy at the assignment operator, for the same reason. This might not happen before, as the compiler might optimise some copy-constructor-calls out. eg. Point p3 = ... is equal to Point p3 = Point(...), so the copy constructor is called instead of the assignment operator. However, if p3 already existed, it has to call the assignment operator, which also creates and returns a copy.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a copy constructor.

```
Point(const Point &p)
: x(p.x),
  y(p.y)
{
    ++count;
}
```